# Can I make an overridden method synchronized?

Tags: java, synchronized, overriding

I am overriding a method from superclass, however I want this method to be synchronized.
Is it allowed? What could be the alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed as it doesn't change the contract but the implementation.

Think that you could always simply add a synchronized block :

```
synchronized(this) {
```

just at the start of the method, which would achieve about the same result. There could also be other (possibly hidden) locks deeper in the method, which makes this really part of the implementation rather than the API.

Comment: You mean `Synchronized block` right? Well I should try this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1612078 You don't need to use a synchronized block as you're allowed to make the whole method synchronized. Use a synchronized block only if you don't always need to synchronize (or if a big part of the method can be unprotected).